# How to find and replace with different UUIDs

Tags: search, replace

I want to replace the following UUIDs with newly generated ones which I have saved in a file.

**Current UUIDs**

```
'uuid': '10000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000',
'uuid': '20000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000',
'uuid': '30000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000',
'uuid': '40000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000',
'uuid': '50000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000',
```

**New UUIDs I want to use**

```
61c1345a-15ef-4286-a97c-a4ade5858eee
6c548dcf-6ede-4342-8735-7cce300a3148
bfbb27df-1a26-49db-8408-85aaa676c4be
e6d2e99e-a4da-41d5-a4e0-7ce2e56a5258
50a2a6c6-57b8-4329-b306-9e361a66d8f7
```

Is there a way of replacing each of my current UUIDs with the new ones I have without manually doing each single one? (I have about 50 to do)

Many thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying this programmatically I would use a tool like Notepad++ and use the block selection feature to copy and paste over "old" data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you should look into regular expressions. To match one of your UUIDs you'll want to use one like this:

```
\d{8}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{10}
```

You can use this to figure out where in the first file you have this pattern, and replace it with the next pattern in the second file.

Comment: \d matches a digit. You wanna use \w to match both letters and digits.